# Error: The client does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config/list/action'

Tags: azure-active-directory, amazon-iam, azure-web-roles

How does one go about translating an Azure permissions error message into the actual permissions needed to solve the problem?

I'm getting an error message when trying to run a WebJob:

> The client does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config/list/action' over scope '/subscriptions/[redacted]/resourceGroups/[redacted]/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/[redacted]/config/publishingcredentials'

Based on this information, how do I determine which role to add, and where?

Note: I do NOT want to grant Contributor access to my registered application. I see that such advice is provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71935589), but I consider that to be a sloppy approach to security; I prefer the 'least privilege' rule in these matters.

My question is about how to translate the information from the error message (e.g. "Microsoft.Web/sites/config/list/action") into the actual IAM permissions I must grant to my application.

Basically I'm looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74156759), but for Azure instead of AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can copy  `Microsoft.Web/sites/config/list/action` from error
> message and search if any [built-in RBAC
> role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles)
> exists with that permission.
>
> There is one built-in RBAC role named **[Website
> Contributor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#website-contributor)**
> having `Microsoft.Web/sites/*` permission that manages websites.

As you prefer least privileges, you can assign **Website Contributor** role to the registered application under your `App service` or `Resource group` based on **scope** from error like below:

[image]

Alternatively, you can also create one **custom RBAC role** with `Microsoft.Web/sites/config/list/action` permission under your subscription like below:

[image]

You can leverage existing built-in role by **cloning it** like this:

[image]

In **`Permissions`** tab, you can either **add** or **remove** permissions based on your requirement like below:

[image]

In **`Assignable scopes`** tab, select scope that can be either **resource group** or **subscription** in which your App Service exists like this:

[image]

After creating the above custom role, you can **assign** it to the registered application under your App service or Resource group like below:

[image]

**Reference:**
[Azure custom roles - Azure RBAC | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles)

Comment: Thank you, that got me past the first set of gates. But now I've hit the [next snag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76651172) in line. What do you suggest? What is meant by that `providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/basic` reference?

Comment: Website Contributor manages **only** websites not web plans.  The `providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/basic` permission is related to **Web plans** that won't work with Website Contributor role. To resolve the error, try assigning **Web Plan Contributor** role also to the registered application under your `Resource group`